# How to create an ansible array of all available aws regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

In an ansible playbook I would like to be able to dynamically pull a list of all available aws regions and iterate over them to perform the same aws task everywhere. This information can be gained with the aws cli command `aws ec2 describe-regions`.  I'm looking for either an ansible task that can produce a list or a way to convert this json into a list that can easily be looped over using `with_items`

```
$ aws ec2 describe-regions 
{
    "Regions": [
        {
            "Endpoint": "ec2.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com", 
            "RegionName": "ap-south-1"
        }, 
        {
            "Endpoint": "ec2.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com", 
            "RegionName": "eu-west-2"
        }, 
        {
            "Endpoint": "ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com", 
            "RegionName": "eu-west-1"
        }, 
        {
            "Endpoint": "ec2.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com", 
            "RegionName": "ap-northeast-2"
        }, 
        {
            "Endpoint": "ec2.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com", 
            "RegionName": "ap-northeast-1"
        }, 
        {
            "Endpoint": "ec2.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com", 
            "RegionName": "sa-east-1"
        }, 
        {
            "Endpoint": "ec2.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com", 
            "RegionName": "ca-central-1"
        }, 
        {
            "Endpoint": "ec2.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com", 
            "RegionName": "ap-southeast-1"
        }, 
        {
            "Endpoint": "ec2.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com", 
            "RegionName": "ap-southeast-2"
        }, 
        {
            "Endpoint": "ec2.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com", 
            "RegionName": "eu-central-1"
        }, 
        {
            "Endpoint": "ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", 
            "RegionName": "us-east-1"
        }, 
        {
            "Endpoint": "ec2.us-east-2.amazonaws.com", 
            "RegionName": "us-east-2"
        }, 
        {
            "Endpoint": "ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com", 
            "RegionName": "us-west-1"
        }, 
        {
            "Endpoint": "ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", 
            "RegionName": "us-west-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [@Jordi's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8972872/jordi-molina) solution I could convert the json of the aws command output using something similar to the following example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - command: "aws ec2 describe-regions"
    register: json_out

  - set_fact:
      region_json: "{{json_out.stdout | from_json}}"
      region_list: []

  # example of itteration over the converted json
  - debug:
      msg: "{{item.RegionName}}"
    with_items: "{{region_json.Regions|default([], true)|list}}"

  # Creates actual list of only region names
  - set_fact:
      region_list: "{{region_list + [item.RegionName] }}"
    with_items: "{{region_json.Regions|default([], true)|list}}"

  - debug:
      var: region_list
```

Answer (score 1):

You could execute the command with the **command** module and register the output.

Then the variable would have a .stdout property with the output. The output is a JSON object. Which can be passed through the jinja filter **from_json** (check http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html)

regards